# JSON does not read special characters

Tags: php, json, encoding, utf-8

When i try to encode the following characters to JSON using PHP: **`æ ø å`**

I will just say `null` where it was supposed to show up. I have the page header encoding set to UTF-8 and i know this encoding will print those letters just fine. But for some reason, it does not work.

Here is my current code:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

if (isset($_GET['count'])) {
    $count = $_GET['count'];

    $data_exists = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM display");
    if (mysql_num_rows($data_exists) > $count) {
        // Next record is available
        $get_data = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM display LIMIT ".$count.",1");
        while ($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_data)) {

            $id = $data['id'];
            utf8_encode($content = $data['content']);

            $return_data = array('id' => $id, 'content' => $content);

            echo json_encode($return_data);

        }
    } else {
        // Next record is not available

    }
}
```

When i run this code, i get this JSON string: `{"id":"1","content":null}`

The database record is as follows:

```
+------+--------------------------------+
|  ID  |             Text               |
+------+--------------------------------+
|    1 | <div class="text">æøå...</div> |
+------+--------------------------------+
```

It works all fine when i am not using any special characters.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: What encoding is the data really in? I'm guessing it's *not* UTF-8, because `json_encode` expects UTF-8 encoded data, and it failing means it's not UTF-8 encoded. Also, `utf8_encode($content = $data['content']);` does nothing.

Comment: you should give more info on the encoding of the real data of the DB. Also to make sure if the data is encoded properly, check the string with `mb_check_encoding()`

Comment: `utf8_encode` only works with `ISO-8859-1` encoding. If your data in DB has other encoding (but not `UTF-8`) you shouldn't use `utf8_encode` for charset converting. Use `iconv` instead.

Comment: @Mostafa
The table collation is set to _utf8_general_ci_
And the table format is _Compact_...
By the way: mb_check_encoding() outputs a 1 to the screen?

Comment: how did you check that? did you stated "UTF-8"? if yes, then your string is utf-8 anyway

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue.

The problem was indeed the encoding as stated in the comments under the question.

I fixed this problem by running the following query before requesting the data:

```
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
```

Just for other users incase they run into a similar problem.